# Python requests get stopped working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a simple Python(2.7) script that looks like this:

```
from requests import get

game_date = '03/16/2017'
headers = {'Referer': 'http://stats.nba.com/standings/',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

response = get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard', 
    params = {'DayOffset': 0, 'LeagueID': '00', 'gameDate': game_date}, 
    headers = headers, 
    timeout = 10)

response.raise_for_status() # raise exception if invalid response

len_resultsets = len(response.json()['resultSets'])

# etc. etc.
```

This used to work (until 2 days ago) on my Linux machine, but now it does not anymore. Without the `timeout` option in `get` it simply sits there and never returns. It still works perfectly fine on my Mac. I didn't change anything. I tried different User Agent strings but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem could arise from a lot of factors outside the code

Comment: @Jerfov2 Like what? can you point me to a few things I can check?

Comment: I mean like, your wifi for example. Is your network setup correctly?

Comment: The code is executed from an AWS EC2 instance so I don't think it's a network issue. Other scripts (referencing other websites) work fine on the same machine.

Comment: Working fine for me on ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04. Value of `len_resultsets` comes out to be 7.

Comment: When running your code on my computer, it works just fine. `get` returns quickly (less than a second) and it gives some valid JSON with it as well. `len_resultsets = len(response.json()['resultSets'])` evalulates to 7

Comment: @SatishGarg yes I can run on other machines, but not on my ubuntu 14.04 instance. What's frustrating is that I don't understand why it stopped working on that specific machine. It was working up to 3/14 but has stopped working since. And since nothing returns there are no useful error messages to work with.

Comment: Can you resolve the name `stats.nba.com` from your AWS instance? If so, can you then `ping` that host (again from your AWS instance).

Comment: @RolandSmith I did `host stats.nba.com` and got 104.80.89.82 and 104.80.89.129. Pinged both and they both work fine. Did I do that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this by using public proxies (via [this project](https://github.com/pgaref/HTTP_Request_Randomizer/tree/7051fd8d4350abd2692c0472ebe31f4a471e86d5)). Not all the public proxies are successful but you can set up a trial and error loop until one is. Something like this:

```
from http.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy
from requests import get

#list of proxies proxies...
req_proxy = RequestProxy()
proxy_list = req_proxy.get_proxy_list()
#

game_date = '03/16/2017'
results_dict = {}
headers = {'Referer': 'http://stats.nba.com/standings/',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

response = ''
len_resultsets = 0
trying = True

while trying:
    try:
        proxies = {'http': random.choice(proxy_list)}
        response = get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard',
                       params = {'DayOffset': 0,
                                 'LeagueID': '00',
                                 'gameDate': game_date}, 
                       headers = headers, 
                       timeout = 30, 
                       proxies = proxies
                      )

        response.raise_for_status() # raise exception if invalid response
        len_resultsets = len(response.json()['resultSets'])

        trying = False

    except:
        time.sleep(5)
```